# Python function runs smoothly twice and then gets stuck in infinite loop

Tags: python, function

I looked at many other questions but couldn't find what I needed, so I'm sorry if this is a repeat.

I am using Python 2.7 through Jupyter Notebook and I have made a function to go through my data to get rid of obvious terrible spikes (making those locations NaN). The function works beautifully twice (the graphs are exactly what I want, I did not include them here because they seem irrelevant), but then it gets stuck and doesn't increment my counters or do anything other than print the variables I use to check what is happening in my code. I also have to clear all the kernels and re-run all previous cells before running this section or else it gets stuck on the very first iteration.

I need to use this function 8 separate times in my script and that is just not possible at the moment. I am fairly new to Python so I am hoping there is an obvious fix that I just cannot see.

Here is the function:

```
def testCR(Acr,binscr,errincr,lamcr,mcr):
    LengthOut = int(np.ceil((lamcr[-1]-lamcr[0])/binscr))
    print('len(Acr)=',len(Acr))
    SpecTestcr = Acr
    LamTestcr = lamcr
    ErrTestcr = errincr
    k = 1
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i <= len(Acr)-1:
        while lamcr[j] <= lamcr[0]+(k*binscr) and lamcr[j] <= lamcr[-1]:
            j += 1
            if j >= len(lamcr):
                break
        print('j=',j)
        testcr = Acr[i:j-1]
        dcr = np.abs(testcr - np.median(testcr))
        mdevcr = np.median(dcr)
        scr = np.divide(dcr,mdevcr) if mdevcr else [0] * len(dcr)
        print('len testcr=',len(testcr))
        print('mdevcr=',mdevcr)
        for q in range(len(testcr)):
            if scr[q] >= mcr:
                SpecTestcr[i+q] = np.nan
                ErrTestcr[i+q] = np.nan
                LamTestcr[i+q] = np.nan
        i = j
        k += 1
        if (i >= len(Acr)-1) or (j >= len(Acr)-1):
            break
    return SpecTestcr, LamTestcr, ErrTestcr
```

And here is how it is returned after calling it:

```
#Start of Call 1
('len(Acr)=', 2030)
('j=', 166)
('len testcr=', 165)
('mdevcr=', 0.014701925686341571)
('j=', 332)
('len testcr=', 165)
('mdevcr=', 0.01341256599231086)
# lots out outputs that are redundant
#Start of Call 2
('len(Acr)=', 2030)
('j=', 166)
('len testcr=', 165)
('mdevcr=', 0.016135353935591987)
# deleted many outputs here
('j=', 2030)
('len testcr=', 41)
('mdevcr=', 0.039457538527604724)
#Start of Call 3
('len(Acr)=', 2030)
('j=', 166)
('len testcr=', 165)
('mdevcr=', 0.014498302694355033)
('j=', 166)
('len testcr=', 0)
('mdevcr=', nan)
('j=', 166)
('len testcr=', 0)
('mdevcr=', nan)
('j=', 166)
('len testcr=', 0)
('mdevcr=', nan)
```

And these last few lines repeat forever unless I stop the code.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time!

Edit:

As reference here is how I am calling it the 3 different times:

```
B0crtest,lam0crtest,Err0crtest=testCR(A0,Bins,A0err,A0oL,2)
B45crtest,lam45crtest,Err45crtest=testCR(A45,Bins,A45err,A45oL,2)
B225crtest,lam225crtest,Err225crtest=testCR(A225,Bins,A225err,A225oL,2)
```

The different numbers (0 45 and 225(22.5)) are just the different half wave plate angles that the data was taken with.

To see what the function does (when it runs correctly) is turn the first graph (below) into the second.

[Graph before function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utmqy.png)

[Graph after function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg8Ds.png)

Comment: So once you break out of `while lamcr[j] <= lamcr[0]+(k*binscr) and lamcr[j] <= lamcr[-1]:`, `j` never gets a new value. `i = j` just keeps giving the same value to `i` and so the outer `while` loop becomes infinite.

Comment: Which while loop is it getting stuck in? What do your *prints* tell you is happening?

Comment: Just as a quick observation, it looks like maybe it's because `j` doesn't satisfy `lamcr[j] <= lamcr[0]+(k*binscr) and lamcr[j] <= lamcr[-1]` and also doesn't satisfy `(j >= len(Acr)-1)`.

Comment: @roganjosh but why would that happen only if the program has been run before? I don't have that problem the first time (or second) time around.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What are ˋˋAcr,binscr,errincr,lamcr,mcrˋˋ? Can you say in words how your logic is supposed to terminate?

Comment: The claim to the "second time" round working is dubious. I could totally understand it working the first time but not working the second time around because Jupyter has an IPython kernel that "remembers" values from previous executions.

Comment: @RylanFeldspar I am having it reference that specific entry in the Lamar array which increments up evenly so it should. If I understand it correctly.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Arc is an array of the divided fluxes from a star spectrum, bins cr is an int of how large of a wavelength range I am looking over for the different iterations, errincr is an array the errors associated with the fluxes, lamar is an array of the wavelengths associated with each flu. Mcr is a variable I can change based on how picky I want to be with getting rid of spikes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi as I showed with the printed outputs, it runs for both the  first and second call but not the 3rd. If I re run it without deleting the kernels it fails immediately.

Comment: You seem to be supplying different inputs or modifying the inputs. Does it hang when receiving the same arguments more than twice?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes. If I give it the same inputs twice in a row it will hang.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Every time I call it the Acr, errincr, and lamcr inputs are different. but binscr and mcr will be the same.